# Java Android OutputStreamWriter IOException

Tags: java, android, networking

I have a code to send request to php page and it worked fine, but suddenly(I don't remember changing anything) it stopped working both on emulator and on real device

```
    URL url = new URL(this.site); 
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))    { 
                Log.e(TAG, "connection is not HttpURLConnection");  
                throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

            }

            try{
                Log.e(TAG, "Trying");
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                Log.e(TAG, "Created connection");
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                Log.e(TAG, "connecting");
                httpConn.connect(); 
                Log.e(TAG, "connected");

                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConn.getOutputStream());
                Log.e(TAG, "created outputstream");
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
     12-25 00:32:14.024: W/System.err(885): java.net.ProtocolException: Does not support output
     12-25 00:32:14.090: W/System.err(885):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:575)
     12-25 00:32:14.090: W/System.err(885):     at com.*****.StringAsyncRetriever.OpenHttpConnection(StringAsyncRetriever.java:122)
     12-25 00:32:14.090: W/System.err(885):     at com.******.StringAsyncRetriever.getData(StringAsyncRetriever.java:66)
     12-25 00:32:14.094: W/System.err(885):     at com.******.StringAsyncRetriever.doInBackground(StringAsyncRetriever.java:38)
     12-25 00:32:14.094: W/System.err(885):     at com.******.StringAsyncRetriever.doInBackground(StringAsyncRetriever.java:1)
     12-25 00:32:14.094: W/System.err(885):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
     12-25 00:32:14.094: W/System.err(885):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
     12-25 00:32:14.094: W/System.err(885):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
     12-25 00:32:14.094: W/System.err(885):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
     12-25 00:32:14.094: W/System.err(885):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
     12-25 00:32:14.094: W/System.err(885):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: What IOException? Message? Stack trace?

Comment: And the exception is...?

Comment: post your stacktrace ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at the source code, that exception is thrown when `doOutput` is not set to `true`:

(From: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-libcore/org/apache/harmony/luni/internal/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnectionImpl.java.htm)

```
public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
    if (!doOutput) {
        throw new ProtocolException("Does not support output");
    }
```

The `HttpURLConnectionImpl` class is extended from Java's `HttpUrlConnection` class which extends `URLConnection`. Looking at the javadocs for that you find:

> protected boolean doOutput
>
> This variable is set by the setDoOutput
>   method. Its value is returned by the getDoOutput method. A URL
>   connection can be used for input and/or output. Setting the doOutput
>   flag to true indicates that the application intends to write data to
>   the URL connection.
>
> The default value of this field is false.

So, you need to do:

```
httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
```

in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that saves me a lot of time wondering.  I see this happening only on Andoird 2.x and 3.x emulators. It is strange.

Comment: I still receive IOException, any ideas?